# What are the '*' and '_' prefixes in css?

Tags: css

Just stumbled upon this in a borrowed css file - something I've never noticed before, and punctuation in context is inherently hard to google:

```
.ez-radio { zoom: 1; *display:inline; _height:15px; }
```

What's the `'*'` prefix do?

And for the matter the underscore in `_height`?

Is this some new CSS3 trickery?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's used for CSS hacks in Internet Explorer.

`*` is IE 6 - 7 only (thank you, mck89!)

`_` is IE 6 and below.

Don't use them. If you need browser specific CSS definitions, use specialized CSS definitions instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Makes sense, and since people who use IE7 or less can eat my shorts, I'll be deleting them :)

Answer (score 1):

Those symbols are used to target IE lower version browsers called it CSS HACKS.
FF, Chrome or Safari always ignored those strings in CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

dont want to duplicate Zanathel's answer, but its important to mention:

1. please do not use them in your stylesheet, keep it hack-free
2. when you need to use hacks, dont use hacks, use [conditional comments](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/), and place your ie specific css in these files